# How to detect the end of this stream in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, node-streams

Trying to understand how to work with this async stream for a Firebase loader. I'm finding:

- when I enable the Firebase Promise, the process stays open even though the last record is output to stdout.
- With Firebase code commented as such, the process closes, but the final event is not written to console.

So I'm guessing Firebase is leaving some connection open that needs to be closed before the process exits, and that if I could figure out how to detect the end of the pipe, I can probably do that.

I've commented the Firebase stuff for now to remove it from the problem, but given this code, how do I run some code after the pipe completes? As it is the done function is not executing.

```
const csv = require('csv');
const fs = require('fs');
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const config = require('../../app-config');
const serviceAccount = require('../../service-account');
const jobConf = require('../../data/category.jobfile');
const _ = require('lodash');

 // configure firebase
 firebase.initializeApp({
  credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: config.firebase.databaseURL,
});
console.log('Loading config', jobConf);

const counts = {
  total: 0,
  new: 0,
  updated: 0,
}

const transformer = (record, done) => {
  const newObj = {};
  const fieldMaps = jobConf.fieldMaps;
  Object.keys(record).forEach((key) => {
    const destination = fieldMaps[key];
    const value = _.get(record, key);
    destination ? _.set(newObj, destination, value) : _.set(newObj, key, value);
  });
  Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      done(null, JSON.stringify(newObj, null, 2));
    });
  // // now we look for existing row
  // firebase.database().ref(`/categories`).orderByChild('identifier').equalTo(newObj.identifier)
  //   .once('value')
  //   .then((snap) => snap.val())
  //   .then((val) => {
  //     if (val) {
  //       console.log('Got value', val);
  //       newObj.lastUpdated = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
  //     } else {
  //       newObj.created = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
  //       newObj.lastUpdated = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
  //       counts.total++;
  //       counts.new++;
  //       done(null, JSON.stringify(newObj, null, 2));
  //     }
  //   })
  //   .catch((err) => {
  //     console.log(err);
  //     done(err);
  //   })
};

const stream = fs.createReadStream(`../../data/${jobConf.sourceFile}`);
const pipe = stream.pipe(csv.parse({columns: true})).pipe(csv.transform(transformer)).pipe(process.stdout);

pipe.on('finish', function () { // not executed
  console.log('Done.');
  console.log('Stats: ', counts);
  process.exit(0);
});
```

Comment: Try returning the Promise to the `transform` function

Comment: Shouldn't be required, it uses a callback for async transformer from the csv.transform library. See `done` calls.

Comment: I've nearly figured it out, it wasn't terminating because process.stdout doesn't emit 'finish' event. I've rerouted to a file and it's nearly working.